# Ionic Runtime Error in Tutorial

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am following the Ionic Tutorial from their docs and when I run:

```
ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2
```

I get no errors. But when I try to run it using

```
ionic serve
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I have done nothing with the code. Is there something wrong with installation of ionic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to move into `MyIonic2Project` folder.Then run as shown below.

```
c:\MyIonic2Project> ionic serve
```